# Python 3.5 in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: python, python3

I would like to install Python 3.5 in my new 18.04 Ubuntu release. I don't want it to be my default version. I just need it to run a specific app. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why? Python 3.6 should already be installed. Why the need for 3.5?

Comment: @Rinzwind As i mentioned, for a specific app. When compiling it, it says it needs Python 3.5 in order to work

Comment: Is there anyone that codes for 3.5 specifically?  Generally I would assume that means 3.5 or higher.  But you do need to start that app with "python3" Not "python" (since python 2 is the default at the moment).

Comment: To be exact on 18.04, `python` is python 2.7.15rc1 and `python3` is 3.6.5 (as of today), on 17.10 however you will get a different result because there `python`is linking to python 3.6.x (not exactly know the version here) and `python2` is linking to 2.7.x. guess they changed it yround again for compatibility reasons.

Comment: ^- not sure whether it properly solves the problem (see [Rinzwind’s comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044807/python-3-5-in-ubuntu-18-04#comment1703563_1044807)), but it does answer the question.

Comment: @Videonauth: That change was likely due to [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/).

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks that's interesting Information.

Comment: Older python packages are very useful for application developers who want to test compatibility of their application. If someone wants to use a specific version they probably have a reason. The reason is not the point here! We all know newer versions are better (usually).

Answer (score 4):

I'ld be more inclined to set up a docker container, but the [deadsnakes ppa](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) does carry various python builds you could install to get exactly the version you need.

For bionic, they do have a few builds.